# Locating / identifying depressions on a DEM (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation

I have a 1m DEM and on this DEM I want to locate the surface depressions. For a reforestation project I would like to know the surface depressions because of the effect they can have on soil moisture and runoff collection.

Comment: Have you tried something? How deep and wide are they?

Answer (score 1):

### r.slope.aspect

A common approach is to calculate the second derivative of the terrain morphology, and identify areas around zero.
Beware that these could be either depressions or peaks. To tell them apart, the sign of the third derivative is needed.

The second derivative(s) can be easily obtained with `r.slope.aspect`:

[image]

Curvature(s) are the overall values you are looking for, but I would suggest the first analysis to be run checking the partial (i.e. directional) derivatives (circled in purple)

Comment: please help me with the way of analysing the outputs of the function. So I do now understand first/second/third order derivatives after some reading up on Google. If I understand correctly the 1st: slope, 2nd: concavity, 3rd: rate of change of concavity?

Now what does partial derivative mean? And how do I interpret the outcomes?